# g++ x86_64 NS_NewGenericModule2

Tags: macos, mozilla, xpcom

I am trying to do extension development, but I am running into an error linking my code -- it's not finding NS_NewGenericModule2.

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "NS_NewGenericModule2(nsModuleInfo const*, nsIModule**)", referenced from:
      _NSGetModule in meta.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

I'm using MacOsX lion... Does anyone have a XPCOM module or a Mozilla Extension with c++ and could share the source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be using some very outdated example code - `NS_NewGenericModule2` has been removed from the Firefox codebase in Firefox 4, along with [major XPCOM changes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM/XPCOM_changes_in_Gecko_2.0). I'm not sure how you managed to compile you code and why the issue only comes up when linking - normally (when using a current XULRunner SDK release) you should get an error already during compilation.

As to current example code, there is one [in the Firefox code base](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/xpcom/sample/). Have a look at `nsSampleModule.cpp` for a module definition example, `nsSample.cpp` contains the actual XPCOM object implementation.

Comment: Do you have any Thunderbird plugin with XPCom (C++ or Java invocation) example?
Thanks for helping me

Comment: @darionascimento: Thunderbird is exactly the same, there is no difference.